# Troubles with getting WiFi to work

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I know it is not the first time this question has been asked. However I was not able to get any previous solution to work, and trust me I've tried everything I could find.

When I first received my RPi and set it up at my apartment, everything worked great including the WiFi, now I'm setting it up at my parents place, and it simply wont connect via WiFi. I've made sure the password and ESSID match, that there is a strong signal when running `iwlist scan wlan0` and that is is over all connected to the network, I can however only connect when I plug in ethernet. So I can SSH into the Pi just fine using the WiFi ip (i.e. the one I get from ifconfig wlan0) while the ethernet cable is plugged in, but if I unplug it the connection is lost, and I'm not able to reestablish it until I plug it back in.

A simple ping command to the Pi while unplugged yields either nothing, `ping: sendto: No route to host` or `ping: sendto: Host is down`.

Below I've added some images, that show my router WiFi settings, and it even shows that my Pi is connected to the router, I also included a screendump of the ifconfig command. I've literally tried everything I could find on the forums, even firmware upgrades and what not. Thanks in advance!

//Andreas

[image: Image of Access Point settings]
[image: Image of Pi on Access Point]
[image: Image of ifconfig on Pi]

Comment: What does `ifconfig eth0` show?

Comment: @anonymoose `ifconfig eth0` yields `inet addr:10.0.0.18  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`

Comment: This might sound crazy, but you could try `sudo ifdown wlan0` while logged in from wifi and see if your connection stays up.

Comment: I was thrown off after using that command, while connected via WiFi IP. `packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.0.0.9 port 22: Broken pipe`

Comment: Do you have another way of connecting to the Pi such as a serial console or HDMI/keyboard?

Comment: I could setup HDMI/keyboard, but I could still connect through ethernet via the other local IP, so `wlan0` is running again now.

Comment: If you can, it might help to see the output of `ifconfig wlan0` while ethernet is disconnected.

Comment: And, if you SSH into the WiFi IP 10.0.0.9 while the Ethernet is connected and type `ping 10.0.0.1` to ping your router, what happens when you then unplug the cable? I have had trouble with the pi wifi going to sleep. So, if the connection stays good with the unplugged cable it might be the same. On a few of my pi's I have a cron job that pings the router each 5 minutes to keep the wifi awake.

Comment: @anonymoose Now things are getting really strange. I'm getting exactly the same results from `ifconfig wlan0` without the ethernet plugged in, the Pi can ping google.com, so it has internet. I just can't ping it or connect locally from any computer. I can even connect to it via SSH when I open a port on my router, and connect through the public ip address, this is however not ideal at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about this to help, though it sounds to me like a software problem. A few things you could try: 1) `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` 2) Reinstall wpa supplicant with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall wpa_supplicant` 3) Backup any files and reimage.